# Update a table and return both the old and new values

Tags: sql, db2

Im writing a VB app that is scrubbing some data inside a DB2 database.  In a few tables i want to update entire columns.  For example an account number column. I am changing all account numbers to start at 1, and increment as I go down the list.  Id like to be able to return both the old account number, and the new one so I can generate some kind of report I can reference so I dont lose the original values.  Im updating columns as so:

```
DECLARE @accntnum INT 
SET @accntnum = 0 
UPDATE accounts
SET @accntnum = accntnum = @accntnum + 1
GO
```

Is there a way for me to return both the original accntnum and the new one in one table?

Comment: I would say use an updatable cursor, reading all records and then updating the current record. But I am not sure about the exact syntax for DB2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DB2 has a really [nifty feature](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statement-result-sets-from-sql-data-changes) where you can select data from a "data change statement". This was tested on DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, but I think that it should also work on at least [DB2 for z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=data-selecting-values-while-updating).

For your numbering, you might considering creating a [sequence](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-sequence), as well. Then your update would be something like:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE acct_seq
     START WITH 1
     INCREMENT BY 1
     NO MAXVALUE
     NO CYCLE
     CACHE 24
;

SELECT accntnum  AS new_acct, old_acct
FROM FINAL TABLE (
    UPDATE accounts INCLUDE(old_acct INT)
    SET accntnum = NEXT VALUE FOR acct_seq, old_acct = accntnum
)
ORDER BY old_acct;
```

The `INCLUDE` part creates a new column in the resulting table with the name and the data type specified, and then you can set the value in the update statement as you would any other field.

Comment: This is close to working except accntnum has type VARCHAR. I tried chainging the old_acct INT to VARCHAR but it still errors out. any suggestions?

Comment: What error do you get?  For VARCHAR, you have to give it a length: `INCLUDE(old_acct VARCHAR(20))`

Comment: Oh duh. ok one last question.  I want the output to be ascending order by the old acct number. can i do it with this somehow?

Comment: I believe you can just use the `ORDER BY` clause. See the edit in the answer above.

Comment: Yea i was attempting to use order by but couldnt figure out the correct placement.  This spot works.  I said that was the last question but i have 1 more and this will be working exactly as I need it to.  In my table i have the possibility of duplicate old_acct.  How can i make this update change all instances of an old_acct to the same new_acct?

Comment: I feel like i need to use the WHERE clause but im not sure how to fit it into this.

Comment: It doesnt look like this is working with a varchar of any length.  I guess it doesnt like the value type sequence is creating.  Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to add an additional column (let's call it `oldaccntnum`) and assign old values to that column as you do your update. 
Then drop it when you no longer need it.

Comment: This is a possible solution.  Could this method cause performance issues if run on a table with a high number of records(1 million+)?

Comment: Any changes on that scale could cause performance issues. My guess is it won't make your update worse than it is. Adding and dropping a column may take some time. Just don't add indices on a new column before you completed your update.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

```
-- create a new table to track the changes.
    - with columns identifying a unique key, old-vale, new-value, timestamp

-- create a trigger on the accounts table 
   to write the old and new values to the new table.
```

But, not knowing all the conditions, it may not be worth the trouble.