# Using a sequencing update, change all duplicate values to the current value in the sequence

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following query working almost how I want to.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE acct_seq
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 NO MAXVALUE
 NO CYCLE
 CACHE 24
;

SELECT accntnum  AS new_acct, old_acct
FROM FINAL TABLE (
UPDATE accounts INCLUDE(old_acct INT)
SET accntnum = NEXT VALUE FOR acct_seq, old_acct = accntnum
)
ORDER BY old_acct;
```

I'm using this to scrub a table in a database, changing all account numbers to a number in the sequence, and then returning the old and new values.  I need it to change all old_acct that have the same value, to the same number in the sequence, and then just return that old_acct/new_acct once.  Currently it is changing each occurrence of the same acctnum to a different number in the sequence. Thanks!

Comment: This is related to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259024/update-a-table-and-return-both-the-old-and-new-values/).

Comment: Yes it is but i felt my original question was answered and this justified a new question, for the sake of being easy to find.

Comment: Sure. I just added it so that the two would be "linked" and show together in the right-hand side.

Comment: Gotcha.  Still learning the ins and outs of SO.  I will be on here a lot :)